# How to detect the event when receiver accept my outgoing call?

Tags: android

I want to know how Android detect when receiver accepts my phone call? Which state does TelephoneManager capture in this time?

Comment: There is no way you can detect when a called is accepted.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen: Is there any document say about it?

Comment: No but there is nothing in the TelephoneManager that can tell you, the PhoneStateListener go from Ringing to Offhook and then Idle. I knew a lot of people who want to intercept the call but none succeed so far.

Comment: @ Hoan Nguyen: thanks for your comment, i am going to dig deeper on this issue. However, I believe there is some ways to detect this state. :)

Comment: I guess you have to look at the source code for this or maybe you can write a service that somehow can detect screen touch and thus deduct if a called is answered depending on the area touched.